# The best way to transfer projects from one eclipse to another

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to transfer everything I'm working on in one eclipse JEE6 project with database to another eclipse program.  I know I will have to reconfigure a lot and rebuild a lot of library files but what is the easiest way to transfer as much as I can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should export you eclipse project as an archive file. Then save the archive file to a thumb drive. Then import it back in your other machine's eclipse instance. The database stuff (if you used eclipse to locally connect to a db and see schema info and such) is stored under `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity\driverStorage.xml` . So you can also copy that file over.

`File->Export->Archive File` and then do `File->Import->Archive File`

The preferred & safer choice is to use a source repository (ie. svn, git, etc) & commit your project there and then check out the source from there.

Comment: There are things I'm assuming you cannot transfer via svn?

Comment: Where do you put the driverStorage.xml file once you've created your new project? What data does it give you can you see it through eclipse?

Comment: @Randnum - it should be in the same area `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity\driverStorage.xml` of the new eclipse. It should show all the database that you have set up to explore through eclipse.