# Move Eclipse to another machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, export

this question may be simple but what's the way to export an existing eclipse project(**with** referenced libraries!) to eclipse on another machine? If I'm using 'Export Runnable Jar' I'm not able to import it on the other machine, but if I'm using 'Export Jar' it w'ont export the referenced libraries.
Thanks.

Comment: How about copy the project's folder?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996419/the-best-way-to-transfer-projects-from-one-eclipse-to-another

Answer (score 0):

just copy the whole workspace-folder to the other machine

Comment: This won't copy the referenced libraries.

Comment: it depends on. where are your referenced libraries located? i suggest, that they have to reside in the workspace or on an artifact-server.
system-dependent artifacts are not a good solution

Comment: yeah they are spread across my whole machine, which is bad. I tried just copying the workspace folder and readd the referenced libraries manually, but it still gives me a red exclamation mark on the other machine.

Comment: then create a folder containing all referenced libraries (excluding the jdk which has to exist on the new machine)

Comment: you should really use `maven` instead of doing manual dependency management

Answer (score 0):

Export: Right-click on the project, select Export, then select General > Archive File.

Import: Right-click in the workspace area, select Import, then select General > Archive File.

'Export Runnable JAR' does not copy the project, rather it produces a runnable build (i.e., the final product).

Copying the entire workspace is also a bad idea.  Workspaces are not meant to be copied, projects are.  The same workspace may not be compatible across all platforms.